# Errno::ENOENT Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mustache

Playing around with mustache and rails tonight and having issues since I've started using mustache.  For some reason on the first request everything works fine, but all subsequent requests I get this:

> Errno::ENOENT in Home#index
>
> Showing /Users/kyle/Code/inout/app/views/home/index.rb where line #22 raised:
>
> No such file or directory - ./home/index.mustache
>   Extracted source (around line #22):

I'm using:

> Rails 3.1.1
>
> Ruby 1.9.2p290

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with reloading the views/templates. I've noticed it today when I was trying mustache_rails3 that after I edit the templates, I would get this error. Since I'm running the server with guard, I tried restarting, and it works, till the next time I edit the template.

Comment: Not for sure.  I've tried it on two machines and I get exactly the same error.